# What is a retention period of deleted Azure SQL Databases?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a question related to Azure SQL Databases.

I know that we can restore databases to any point in time (7 or 35 days) for different tiers in Azure. That is fine.

However, I am wondering how long the deleted Azure SQL databases will be available to restore for.

Does anybody know?
Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleted databases can be restored to the point in time of deletion during the retention period of the service tier they were in. (currently that is Basic: 7 days; Standard and Premium: <s>35 days</s> [7 days](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/default-backup-retention-period-for-dtu-based-azure-sql-databases-is-changing-soon/)).
For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#deleted-database-restore
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups

Also, if you delete the SQL server that was hosting the databases, all the backups are GONE instantly.

Backups will be stored till retention period: Microsoft docs quote below(emphasis mine): and this is covered on  [Overview of business continuity with Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity) in Perform a point-in-time restore section

> You can use the automated backups to recover a copy of your database to a known good point in time, **provided that time is within the database retention period**.

Comment: Hi, I have actually read those articles and I couldn't find that answer. Might I ask where did you find that answer?

Comment: thanks, @adam.bielasty https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-restore-deleted-database-portal look at the comments

Comment: Thank you @4c74356b41. it looks like Diego Pomatta works for Microsoft and he put that comment, so it is right

Comment: To clarify, the retention period you mentioned that these deleted database backups are managed with, is that the short-term (PiTR) or long-term (LTR) retention policy?

Comment: short term, this doesnt apply to long term, they are stored outside of sql, cant delete them by deleting sql