# Failed to restore deleted SQL Server database from Azure portal: xx has not existed long enough to support restores

Tags: azure-sql-database

I deleted a database at Azure 7 days ago.
I realized I really would like to read just one table - and in the Azure Portal, under SQL server -> Data Management -> Deleted databases, I found the deleted database.

Clicking the database, I can restore it by a point-in-time.
The page header is
Create SQL Database - Restore database
Select a backup source and details. Additional settings will be defaulted where possible based on the backup selected.
Source Database: 
Earliest restore point 2024-02-08 00:00:00 UTC
Restore point (UTC) 02/08/2024 8:32:16 AM
Choose a restore point between the earliest restore point and the database deletion time.
(From another suggestion I tried to move the restore point back 5 mins with the same error)

Database details
Enter required settings for this database, including picking a logical server and configuring the compute and storage resources

Database name _2024-02-08T08-32Z

Clicking on Review + Create gives me :
Product details             SQL database
by Microsoft
Terms of use  |  Privacy policy
Estimated cost per month
14.72 USD
Terms
By clicking "Create", I (a) agree to the legal terms and privacy statement(s) associated with the Marketplace offering(s) listed above; (b) authorize Microsoft to bill my current payment method for the fees associated with the offering(s), with the same billing frequency as my Azure subscription; and (c) agree that Microsoft may share my contact, usage and transactional information with the provider(s) of the offering(s) for support, billing and other transactional activities. Microsoft does not provide rights for third-party offerings. For additional details see Azure Marketplace Terms.
Basics Subscription Azure subscription 1
Resource group ResourceGroup
Source Database old-db-name
Source Point-in-time
Restore point (UTC) 2024-02-08 08:32:16 UTC
Region northeurope
Database name old-db-name_2024-02-08T08-32Z
Server db-name
Database level customer-managed key Not configured
Database level user assigned managed identity Not configured
Backup storage redundancy Locally-redundant backup storage

Azure now tries to restore the database, but within a few seconds i get this error:
Microsoft.SQLDatabase.restoreDeletedDatabaseExistingServer_bc695
The source database, 'db-name', dropped on '2/8/2024 8:32:16 AM', has not existed long enough to support restores. Click here for details

Clicking on details give me the same message plus
The source database, 'db-name', dropped on '2/8/2024 8:32:16 AM', has not existed long enough to support restores. (Code: RestoreIneligibleDroppedDatabaseShortLifespan)

The wording is a bit odd - searching by this error message gives me nothing.

Any help on figuring out the error message?

Thanks in advance

- René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to restore deleted SQL Server database from Azure portal: xx has not existed long enough to support restores

Deleted databases can be restored to the point in time till [7 days](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/default-backup-retention-period-for-dtu-based-azure-sql-databases-is-changing-soon/) after it got deleted after 7 days you cannot retain the database.

Here it is mentioned that in [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#deleted-database-restore)

> You can restore a deleted database to the deletion time, or an earlier point in time, on the same server by using the Azure portal

You can also refer this similar issue on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626373/what-is-a-retention-period-of-deleted-azure-sql-databases#:%7E:text=Deleted%20databases%20can%20be%20restored%20to%20the%20point,days;%20Standard%20and%20Premium:%2035%20days%207%20days%29.)

Comment: So I basically was too late... The wording could be more helpful here...